# Why does `ruby -version` raise a NameError exception for 'rsion'?

Tags: ruby, exception, nameerror

```sh
C:\RubyDevKit>ruby -version
```

```
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]
-e:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `rsion' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `ruby` executable command, like most Unix-ish commands, allows you to combine multiple single character command line options or flags into one.

That means

```sh
ruby -version
```

is the same as

```sh
ruby -v -e rsion
```

`-e` means "run the following Ruby code". The following code is:

```ruby
rsion
```

And there is no variable or method of that name. Ergo, you get a `NameError`.

To get Ruby's version output, run:

```
ruby --version
```